# Supporting Whatif and Confirm responses

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

There are a plethora of questions here on SO and elsewhere explaining how to propagate `-Confirm` throughout one's cmdlet to nested cmdlets, etc. What I do not find, however, is how to propagate the *response* to that prompt. That is, once a user answers this prompt...

```
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

... one would reasonably assume that my cmdlet may now *act* on the user's response to that prompt. That is certainly true in part: both `Suspend [S]` and `Help [?]` are localized operations and those work fine.

But my main issue is with recognizing and acting upon `Yes to All` and `No to All`.
In both C# ( via `Cmdlet.ShouldProcess()` ) and PowerShell ( via `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess()` ) one only gets a Boolean result from which I can only surmise:

- `true` is either [Y] or [A].
- `false` is either [N] or [L].

I had hopes initially that, though not documented as such to say so, `ShouldContinue` would be leveraging internal cmdlet state to make this distinction, but experiments with scripted cmdlets showed this not to be the case.

In fact, the only possible workaround I have found thusfar is [Jeffrey Snover's early rendition](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/02/25/supporting-whatif-confirm-verbose-in-scripts.aspx) (circa 2007!) of a Should-Process function for PowerShell, presumably before the "official" `Cmdlet.ShouldProcess` and `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess` were introduced.

I find it hard to believe that the PowerShell team forgot to allow distinguishing Yes/Yes to All and No/No to All; rather I assume I am merely overlooking it.

**So my question in short form is:** For both compiled cmdlets and scripted cmdlets, how can I distinguish `Yes` from `Yes to All` and `No` from `No to All` ?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the `Yes to all` option means to say "Yes, do this operation on all items which I'm currently working on", not "Yes, do every operation possible and don't ask me again". One way to test this is to pipe an array to a function which supports ShouldProcess which internally calls an inner function (which also supports ShouldProcess) with a single item at a time. You will see that, at least on PowerShell v4.0 on my Win 8.1 machine, the outer function which I have piped the array to does not ask for the other items in the array. However, the inner function, which is called many times, as opposed to being called once with an array for input, will ask once every time it is called.

We can test this behaviour using the following function and inner function:

```
function Test-ShouldProcess
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $true)]
    PARAM (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        $InputObject
    )

    PROCESS
    {
        if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($InputObject, "Do stuff to it"))
        {
            Write-Host "Doing stuff to $InputObject"
            Test-ShouldProcess_InnerFunc -InputObject $InputObject
        }
    }
}

function Test-ShouldProcess_InnerFunc
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $true)]
    PARAM (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        $InputObject
    )

    PROCESS
    {
        if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($InputObject, "Do internal stuff to it"))
        {
            Write-Host "Doing internal stuff to $InputObject"
        }
    }
}
```

If we call the outer function by piping an array to the function, like so:

```
"item1", "item2" | Test-ShouldProcess -Confirm
```

Given that we response "Yes to all" on every prompt, we'll get the following output:

```
Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Do stuff to it" on target "item1".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): A
Doing stuff to item1

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Do internal stuff to it" on target "item1".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): A
Doing internal stuff to item1
Doing stuff to item2

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Do internal stuff to it" on target "item2".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): A
Doing internal stuff to item2
```

Observe that it asks once for the "Do stuff to it" and then once for "Do internal stuff to it". The next line, immediately after the inner function has executed, is the output from the outer function on the second item in the array, _without prompting, since we answered "Yes to all". The outer function for the second item again calls the inner function as a single item call and PowerShell therefore prompts the user again.

The reason PowerShell prompts again is that this is new instructions working on a new set of data. So as long as it's the same instruction working on a list of data, the "Yes for all" will not ask again for later items in the list, but for new instructions or new *sets* of data it should again ask.

If the user does not want the be prompted to confirm at all, the user should not use the `-Confirm` switch and possibly even change the `ConfirmPreference` setting or perhaps use a `-Force` switch.

Comment: My reaction to your answer is: _thank you!_ You provide some helpful insight, Robert, as to how the functionality is all self-contained and one does not need additional output based on the implementation of the mechanism. But my reaction to the _content_ of your answer is: _Waah! That is a poor user experience._ In essence, what you are saying is PowerShell gives prompts that the _writer_ of the code would understand/appreciate, but it is not very useful to a _user_ of the code.

Comment: The _writer_ of the code has the option to write the code in such a way that the _user_ does not get this experience, by working with set based operations. I'm not sure how PowerShell should have handled it differently. The only other option I see is that `Yes to all` would mean `don't ask me for anything again`, which I would personally not like. I see the `don't ask me for again for this set of data` to be a good implementation. Also, if the user does not want to be prompted for anything at all, the user should not add the `-Confirm` switch.